# How can the data in the DataGrid be populated asynchronously in a streaming fashion?

Tags: c#, winforms

In a Windows C# application form I load more than 500,000 records from a SQL Server database for analysis.

```
SELECT TOP 500000 * FROM MobileTrans
```

When I run above query in SQL Server Management Studio data shows up immediately and takes 15 sec to load be completed. But when I run this query in my Windows application, it takes 15 sec without showing anything in the data grid, after that data show in data grid suddenly.

How can I retrieve results of query async same as SQL Server Management Studio in my windows data grid form?

Please send a small sample of code.

Comment: execute your query in a separate thread.

Comment: @Selman22 That wouldn't make it "stream" any better.

Comment: how I can bind data grid to another thread when start loading?

Comment: 1,000,000 records in a grid, displayed on a screen?  Wow.

Comment: I think this is a *good question* (about an X problem) and that people should focus on *that* (instead of Y). *How can one stream data to a DataGrid?* That is, imagine there are only 15 results, but each result takes a second to load, should the user have to wait 15 seconds to see *any* results? The fundamental question is the same. *How can the data in the DataGrid be populated asynchronously in a streaming fashion?* Too many opinions and not enough hard answers.

Comment: @HadiSharifi - it may be good idea to ask *separate* question that address streaming itself, not show the data portion that covered in the answer/comments already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need *to show* 1mln records to anyone. None can see them all contemporary. 
So first load reasonable amount of data one could see and operate in your app.

In short: use server side paging of the data if this is only about presentation.

By reducing in this way dramatically amount of data, you *may* avoid async processing at all.

If you need, by the way, process it in async I would go for populating data retrieved from DB into storage (`Queue<T>`, `List<T>`....) which is a source for visual element you visualize data on.

Consider that this can easily jump into fairly complicated scenarios, as it's not absolutely clear to me how complex your app is. So, may be the first solution would reveal as the best one.

**EDIT**

Here, may be, a useful example about how can be that (defered loading) achieved.

[Implementing Virtual Mode with Just-In-Time Data Loading in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171624%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: While true (about Y), this doesn't even make an attempt to answer the post (X).

Comment: No this is not good answer, why sql server management studio provide this feature? also I using custom analysis grid that need this data loaded in memory in client side!

Comment: @HadiSharifi The DataGrid probably won't be able to do useful analytically stuff until everything is loaded, in which case streaming isn't useful. However, I do think it's a fair question - how to Data Bind (or otherwise populate) a DataGrid from streamed data. (For instance, it might be a *small* result-set that takes a long time to load each row.)

Comment: +1. @HadiSharifi - this is exact answer to your question - "how to quickly show records" - show as many as you can show quickly. If you don't know how to do paging of SQL results - maybe you should ask different question. I.e. LINQ `Take`/`Skip` can give you one way to do paging.

Comment: @user2864740 for question I used data grid to understand everyone, I know data grid can not good for analysis, In my project data grid extended for analysis.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov This is **not** the answer to the question: "How can I retrieve results of query async same as SQL Server Management Studio in my windows data grid form?" where *streaming behavior* was discussed above.

Comment: @HadiSharifi: show to the user and process in memory are different things. You need to load data for user as fast as you can and show only what is relevant to him (user). Processing data is another thing. You can combine them naturally, so first load first page for the user visualization, after merge the rest of data (may be also devided in pages) for processing it.

Comment: @Tigran What good would "populating data" into Queue/List help? How can that be sensibly connected to the DataGrid?

Comment: I know but this is a user requirements, user said: "Why sql server management studio can load data immediatly but your application can not, When I press load data button, I think your app in hangs!"

Comment: @user2864740: those are just examples of data one could have chosen. it depends on the actual ui control one is going to use and actual app case. consider them as an example.

Comment: @Tigran How about a **DataGrid**?

Comment: @HadiSharifi: I edit my post with link to the article relevant to this discussion.

Comment: @user2864740: I edited my answer with the link with defered loading on DataGridView.